# Sometimes Spark lose connection between nodes

Tags: apache-spark

I occasionally get this problem: 
When I run `sbin/stop-all.sh`, it says: `no org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker to stop` but I do have many running workers needed to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

One issue that I sometimes have that may be related:

If you run `start-all.sh` with config X and then change the configuration to Y (say by modifying spark-en.sh, slaves files, etc), then when you run `stop-all.sh` it will try to stop things according to configuration Y and not configuration X.